# HDFS temp directory in rmr.options

Tags: r, hadoop, rhadoop

I'm new in Hadoop so exuce me if the question is stupid. I have a local single-node cluster.
I'm trying to execute a simple MapReduce job in RHadoop and I get this message:

```
> wordcount('/data/complete_works_of_shakespeare.txt')
Error creating temp dir in hadoop.tmp.dir /app/hadoop/tmp due to Permission denied
Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in mr(map = map, reduce = reduce, combine = combine, vectorized.reduce,  : 
      hadoop streaming failed with error code 255 Also warnings: 
1: In rmr.options("backend") :
  Please set an HDFS temp directory with rmr.options(hdfs.tempdir = ...)
2: In rmr.options("hdfs.tempdir") :
  Please set an HDFS temp directory with rmr.options(hdfs.tempdir = ...)
3: In rmr.options("backend") :
  Please set an HDFS temp directory with rmr.options(hdfs.tempdir = ...)
4: In rmr.options("backend.parameters") :
  Please set an HDFS temp directory with rmr.options(hdfs.tempdir = ...)
```

What should I do to set all this options? How should the path to hdfs.tempdir look like? 
I'd want to set the temp directory to (if I understand right what R wants from me)):

```
 hduser@nina:~$ hadoop fs -ls /
 14/08/10 12:52:47 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for      your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
 Found 6 items
 ...
 drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2014-08-10 00:04 /temp
```

Btw I've already tried

```
rmr.options(backend="hadoop")
NULL
Warning:
In rmr.options(backend = "hadoop") :
  Please set an HDFS temp directory with rmr.options(hdfs.tempdir = ...)
```

Please help. Many thanks.

UPD:

Also tried:

```
 hduser@nina:~$ sudo chmod -R 777 '/app/hadoop' 
 hduser@nina:~$ sudo chmod -R 777 '/tmp'
```

Doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify if you have permissions on the app/hadoop directory to create a folder. Try chown on the directory.For example:

```
sudo chown <userid> <directory_path>
```

Comment: just solved the problem by adding property code to conf/hdfs-site.xml

`<property>
      <name>dfs.permissions</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>`

Thanks anyway!